# How to detect mid-function value changes to const parameter?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

I ran into a nasty bug in some of my code. Here's the simplified version:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    std::string s;
    
    void run(const std::string& x)
    {
        // do some "read-only" stuff with "x"
        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        // Since I passed X as a const referece, I expected string never to change
        // but actually, it does get changed by clear() function
        clear();

        // trying to do something else with "x", 
        // but now it has a different value although I declared it as 
        // "const". This killed the code logic.
        std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;

        // is there some way to detect possible change of X here during compile-time?
    }
    
    void clear()
    {
        // in my actual code, this doesn't even happen here, but 3 levels deep on some other code that gets called
        s.clear();
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.s = "test";
    a.run(a.s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the code that calls a.run() use to be used for all kinds of strings in the past and at one point, I needed the exact value that object "a.s" had, so I just put a.s in there and then some time later noticed program behaving weird. I tracked it down to this.

Now, I understand why this is happening, but it looks like one of those really hard to trace and detect bugs. You see the parameter declared as const & and suddenly it's value changes.

Is there some way to detect this during compile-time? I'm using CLang and MSVC.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not pass the string by value instead?

Comment: A constant reference doesn't guarantee the thing the reference refers to wont change on you.  What it does do is guarantee that you don't change it yourself accidentally.  If you want to make sure it never changes, pass by value so you have your own copy.  I don't think you'll find a tool to "fix" this.

Comment: Problem here is that member variable `s` is aliased to parameter `x`. If `run` is not supposed to affect the object state, then it could be declared as `const` and the compiler would then flag the `clear` call. Or if run is not supposed to use the object state then it could be declared as `static` instead. But the way it is now looks like `run` was designed to fool the compiler, so it's not a total surprise that it manages to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude when I first wrote the code, the clear() function didn't even exist. It was added later. Even then, the strings passed to a.run() were always something else, not A member variables. It all worked fine. The code I posted here is the simplified version. In actual code, it goes many layers deep and person touching a.run() much later never expected such side effects. So, yeah, passing by value solved the bug, but that is not my question here.

Comment: @dxiv. Thanks for commenting. run() was never made const because it did affect some other member variables initially (still does) and "x.clear()" was added later (but before a.run() parameter was changed). I was hoping there's some tool or perhaps static analysis that would detect this "aliasing".

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way to detect this during compile-time?

I don't think so. There is nothing inherently wrong about modifying a member variable that is referred by a const reference, so there is no reason for the compiler to warn about it. The compiler cannot read your mind to find out what your expectations are.

There are some usages where such wrong assumption could result in definite bugs such as undefined behaviour that could be diagnosed if identified. I suspect that identifying such cases in general would be quite expensive computationally, so I wouldn't rely on it.

---

Redesigning the interface could make that situation impossible For example following:

```
struct wrapper {
    std::string str;
};


void run(const wrapper& x);
```

`x.str` will not alias the member because the member is not inside a `wrapper`.